# How to avoid LockObtainFailedException in JUnit App Engine LocalSearchService?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I'm using App engine Standard env and my services use the [Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/search/).

So basically in my service I do something like:

```
IndexSpec indexSpec = IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName(indexName).build();
Index index = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(indexSpec);
index.putAsync(document);
```

But when I run my JUnit tests I often get the following exception:

> Apr 17, 2018 11:25:33 AM com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService indexDocumentForApp
>   SEVERE: Unable to access index
>   com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/Users/freddyboucher/Private/Programming/LearnKeeper/learnkeeper-server/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/indexes/dGVzdA/Qk9PS1M..P/write.lock
>       at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:85)
>       at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.init(IndexWriter.java:1562)
>       at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:1090)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.getIndexWriter(LocalSearchService.java:800)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.indexDocumentForApp(LocalSearchService.java:290)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.LocalSearchService.indexDocument(LocalSearchService.java:268)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.invokeApiMethodJava(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:657)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.callInternal(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:612)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:569)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$AsyncApiCall.call(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:541)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable$1.run(Executors.java:533)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedCallable.call(Executors.java:530)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented anywhere but adding:

```
LocalSearchServiceTestConfig.getLocalSearchService().stop()
```

in my @After method fixes the issue.

I also found usefull to add:

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("WEB-INF"));
```

So the final solution is:

```
  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    LocalSearchServiceTestConfig.getLocalSearchService().stop();
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("WEB-INF"));
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
private LocalServiceTestHelper memoryDatastore;

@Before
public void setup() {
   LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig dsConfig = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig();
   memoryDatastore = new LocalServiceTestHelper(dsConfig);
   memoryDatastore.setUp();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
   memoryDatastore.getLocalService("search").stop();
   memoryDatastore.tearDown();
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you simply forget to add a `LocalSearchServiceTestConfig` to your test config.  For example:

```
    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
            new LocalServiceTestHelper(
                    new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig(),
                    new LocalSearchServiceTestConfig());

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        helper.tearDown();
    }
```